# How do I add two numbers in sign-magnitude format without converting to binary

Tags: computer-science

I've google a bunch of answers and I'm still stuck on these two questions:

> 3.6 Assume 185 and 122 are unsigned 8-bit decimal integers. Calculate `185 – 122`. Is there overflow, underflow, or neither?
>
> 3.7 Assume 185 and 122 are signed 8-bit decimal integers stored in sign-magnitude format. Calculate `185 + 122`. Is there overflow, underflow, or neither?

So 3.6 first:
So 185 is represented as 10111001 if it's an unsigned binary number. and 122 is 01111010 as an unsigned number. When you do the subtraction:

```
10111001
01111010
00111111
```

But I'm stuck on 3.7.

So I think 185 in signed number is `10111001 = -57`. First is this right? But how do I add this to 01111010?

I’m a bit stuck on how to do this in other ways besides converting to decimal -> doing the math -> reconvert answer to binary. I’ve looked around the internet but I can’t find a good resource… so how do you add numbers when they are in signed magnitude format. And for clarification… when we say signed magnitude, we don’t mean ones complement or twos complement. So the question is 185 + 122. In signed format, 185 is 10111001 and if the greatest magnitude bit is 1, it’s negative so 10111001 = -57. 122 is 01111010 = 122. So adding them together is 65 = 01000001 in binary. Is there a way to do this without converting to decimal and byworking with teh binary alone?

Answer (score 1):

> In computer science, the sign bit is a bit in a signed number representation that indicates the sign of a number. Only signed numeric data types have a sign bit, and its place is usually the leftmost, where the most significant bit in unsigned numbers resides. Floating-point numbers in IEEE format are always signed, with the sign bit in the leftmost position. Typically if the sign bit is 1 then the number is negative (in the case of two’s complement integers) or non-positive (for ones’ complement integers, sign-and-magnitude integers, and floating-point numbers), while 0 indicates a non-negative number (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit)

N bits can represent –(2^(n-1)- 1) to (2^(n-1) - 1)

Now as far as your question is concerned, I would suggest you to use the same method used by computers to perform subtraction of binary numbers i.e in 2s complement format addition. You can use direct subtraction but not advisable.

for example:-
Assume 185 and 122 are signed 8-bit decimal integers stored in sign-magnitude format. Calculate 185 + 122. Is there overflow, underflow, or neither?

Answer: **51 and safe operation**. How?

185 -> 1011 1001

since the leftmost bit is 1, so it is negative. Leave the most significant bit which is the 1, which leaves you with:

011 1001

Now you want to take the 2′s complement, simply switch every 0 to 1 and every 1 to 0, and add one to the result. You will get:

100 0111

Hence 185 -> 1100 0111 (-71) in 8 bit signed representation according to our computer program. So therefore the solution to 185 + 122 as 8 bit integers is actually -71 + 122 = 51.

```
185(-71)    ->      1011 1001

+122        ->      1000 0110

-----------------------------

 051        ->      0011 0011
```

Now, this might seem like an incorrect result but that's the limitation of using only 8-bit storage and according to our computers and the definition of signed bit representation this is, in fact, the correct result required in this case.

Comment: But the question wants me to do it in sign magnitude format and not twos complement

Comment: I have provided the solution at the end in signed magnitude format in the grey section. I have used 2s complement format just to verify the fact that what we have obtained the correct result.